# Adding new documents automatically to Amazon CloudSearch Domain

Tags: amazon-s3, command-line-interface, aws-sdk, amazon-cloudsearch

I have created a CloudSearch Domain. Using `CLI` data is successfully uploaded to the domain. Data is copied from S3 to CloudSearch domain using command-

```
cs-import-documents -d searchdev3 --source s3://mybucket/html
```

I am wondering how the data will be added to search domain later when a new file is added to S3 bucket.

Can we perform any of the following-

1. Create some kind of schedule that will upload the documents to Search Domain or
2. Any way to automatically detect if any new file is added to S3 and upload it directly to Search Domain.

Above options seems to be feasible but performing uploading operation manually every time does not seems to be a good idea at all.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use the AWS Lambdas event processing service. It is pretty simple to set up an event stream based on S3 (see http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/NotificationHowTo.html)

Your Lambda would then submit a search document to CloudSearch based on the S3 event. For an example of submitting a document from a Lambda, see https://gist.github.com/fzakaria/4f93a8dbf483695fb7d5